# Oxidize Zinc or Nickel in black nickel plating to get browns?

Tags: reaction-control, electroplating

I have a black nickel plating solution that is comprised of the following:

Nickel (II) Sulfate (45-50% by weight)
Zinc Sulfate Heptahydrate (20-24%)
Ammonium Thiocyanate (20-23%)
Zinc Chloride (1-3%)

I plan on plating brass.  Once I plate the brass with the black nickel, is there anything I can apply to get the black nickel to oxidize into browns?  Would a soak in hydrogen peroxide do anything to the zinc or nickel to produce browns?

I know its possible, just don't know how.

Comment: It is difficult to imagine a solution containing about 90% of solids like nickel and zinc sulfates, plus others. Are you sure it is a solution ? Is it not the composition of the solid stuff to be dissolved in water later on ?

Comment: I pulled the breakdown from the SDS sheet.  It is already dissolved in water, I guess they don't list water as an ingredient.
 https://caswellplating.com/content/sds/Black%20Nickel.pdf

Comment: So which volume of water is used to dissolve $1, 10$ or $100$ grams of this mixture ?

Comment: I called the provider and they didn't know the amount weight of ingredients in the solution  All i know is the bottle is 8oz total volume liquid (water+ ingredients) and the SDS sheet lists what I listed above. 
 https://caswellplating.com/content/sds/Black%20Nickel.pdf